# Will we burninate the [python-2.x] tag in 2020?

Tags: discussion, burninate-system

The title has it all, but if you don't understand, I'll fill you in.

Around Pycon 2020, support for the legacy Python versions (2.x series) will be discontinued. (See [this website](https://pythonclock.org) as to what I am talking about.)

So, at that time, will we burninate the [python-2.x] tag? (Not to make bets or assumptions, but I assume by that time most will migrate to Python 3 ( or maybe even greater. ) . )

**NOTE:** I know this will affect many questions, but again, just wondering.

Comment: This only happens when no one could possibly be using an older version (such as in the case with parse.com which is a service that no longer exists). Unless for some reason it becomes impossible to have an older version in 2020 (I don't see how that would be possible), burnination would not make any sense.

Comment: "Not to make bets or assumptions, but I assume by that time most will migrate to Python 3".  Well, I'd take the other side of that bet: Python 2 will be in use forever, because people don't want to change perfectly working code.  (I sure don't.)

Comment: Considering that [we still get Fortran 77 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45900942/interchanging-dummy-variables-in-fortran-77), the implication that we should "burninate" a tag because the associated technology has been "superseded" strikes me as utterly absurd.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. The interpreter will still exist, as will plenty of software targeted at it, and therefore questions about it.

Answer (score 10):

Even if every Python 2 programmer instantly switched to Python 3 on that day and swore a blood oath to forsake all Python 2 work, even if every line of Python 2 code was instantly upgraded into working Python 3, even if every Python 2 module is immediately replaced by a Python 3 one, we would not burninate the Python 2 tags.

We don't burninate tags because they refer to obsolete technology. Disuse is not a valid reason for burnination. We burninate tags that we shouldn't have had to begin with.